# $a_n\leqslant c, a_0=c$, then $\limsup_n a_n\leqslant c$?

Tags: real-analysis

(1.) If I know that $a_n\leqslant c, a_0=c, a_n<c, n\geqslant 1$, does then follow that $\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n\leqslant c$?

(2.) If I have a sequence $(b_n)$ and I if I want to show that $\limsup_{n\to\infty}b_n\leqslant d$, is it then enough to show that $b_0=d$ and $b_n<c, n\geqslant 1$?

**Edited**

I think (1.) is true and (2.) can be answered with yes.

Since if I simply use the definition of the limit superior, we have
$$
\sup_{n\geq k}a_n\leq c~\text{for all }k\geq 0,
$$
hence
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{k\to\infty}\sup_{n\geq k}a_n\leq\lim_{k\to\infty}c=c.
$$

Comment: I don't really see the difference between questions (1) and (2). By the way shouldn't the condition $b_n<c$ be $b_n<d$ in (2)? And a small remark : the value of $a_0$ or $b_0$ doesn't change anything to the limit superior, so these condition can be dropped.

Answer (score 1):

(1) and (2): If there is some $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $a_n \le c$ for $n\ge N$, then we have $\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n \le c$.

This however doesn't implies $\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n = c$. Consider
$ a_n = n^{-1} $
with $c = 1$ and $N=1$.

**Aside:**
We have $\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n \le c$ if and only if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists some $N\in\mathbb N$ such that for all $n\ge N$ follows $a_n < c + \epsilon$.

Comment: For all $n\geqslant 1$ it is $a_n\leqslant c$. But why does this imply that $\limsup_n a_n\leqslant c$?

Comment: "We have $\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n \le c$ if and only if there is some $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $a_n\le c$ for $n\ge N$" is simply false.

Comment: @user251257 you can use your own example : if $a_n=n^{-1}$ then $\limsup_{n\to \infty} a_n=\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n=0$, but $a_n>0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. & .@Arnaud: sorry, fixed the answer

Comment: Please have a look on my edit.

Comment: @Rhjg, I never suggested that (1) or (2) is wrong. In your previous version, you conclude that $\limsup a_n = c$, which is wrong.

Comment: @user251257 Yes, you are right.